# how to store and edit the mobile number with country codes?

Tags: javascript, php

I've asked once but I didn't get the answers.

```
 var phoneno = /^\+?([0-9]{3})\)?[-. ]?([0-9]{3})[-. ]?([0-9]{4})$/;
```

this is how I learnt to validate the numbers + error and...
I also have the Mobile bigint(20) & country varchar(200), in my table "users".
what I want to do is to use another file "countries.php" to get their codes in mobile input in "signup.php" page and store them both into the database.
for example, user chooses 'US +1' the country code will appear in mobile section.

```
$countryArray = array(
    'AD'=>array('name'=>'ANDORRA','code'=>'376'),
    'AE'=>array('name'=>'UNITED ARAB EMIRATES','code'=>'971'), ...
function countrySelector($defaultCountry = "", $id = "", $name = "", $classes = ""){
    global $countryArray; // Assuming the array is placed above this function

    $output = "<select id='".$id."' name='".$name."' class='". $classes."'>";

    foreach($countryArray as $code => $country){
        $countryName = ucwords(strtolower($country["name"])); // Making it look good
        $output .= "<option value='".$code."' ".(($code==strtoupper($defaultCountry))?"selected":"").">".$code." - ".$countryName." (+".$country["code"].")</option>";
    }

    $output .= "</select>";

    return $output; // or echo $output; to print directly
}
```

not to mention I downloaded the file zip. and I don't really know how to add or use the " `use`", please be more specific, like give with examples. thanks

Comment: You would have to use Javascript for this. What have you tried so far?

Comment: @KIKOSoftware technically I used to copy the things which everyone was telling me. and it didn't work. and could you please tell me how to do that?
how to get the code in the mobile section?

Comment: No, I can't, for two reasons: 1. You code is incomplete, there is no mobile input field. This is not working code, how can I work with that? 2. You have to, at least, show that you attempted something. I see not even a sliver of Javascript code.